# How to `list2env()` (or pipe into `assign()`) within a function call?

Tags: r, magrittr, r-environment

I have a use-case for mapping a function to a vector and then assigning the results to individual objects in the parent environment - not the global environment, but the environment that the `map()` was called from. Specifically, this is all happening within a function, so I want to assign these objects to the function's environment for subsequent use within the function call, and only there.

I understand that you can specify environments either by ascending numeric position, with the global as 1, or by counting back from the current environment, namely using `rlang::caller_env()`. By either method, though, I have no reliable method of specifying the desired function execution environment in cases like this. As the below reprex shows, I can get it working in one specific case with `rlang::caller_env(6)`, but it's obvious that counting exactly 6 frames back happens to work in this one case, with its specific pipe chain and sequence of operations, and any situation could have any other needed value there - I only found that 6 was the right number here by printing the traceback within the function. When using `map()`, it's 13 or something, probably because of all the nested function calls within `map()`. And I can't get it working at all with `list2env()`

So what I'm looking for is some argument I can provide to either `list2env()` or `assign()` that will clearly and consistently cause the assignment to occur specifically in the environment of the function that I'm using them within, even if I call those functions at the end of a pipe chain.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

## Trying to assign the value 'foo' to an object named 'bar' in a specific
## location

# Fails because `bar` is assigned in the pipe execution evironment
'foo' %>% assign(x = 'bar')
exists('bar')
#> [1] FALSE

# Works because `pos = 1` refers specifically to the global environment
'foo' %>% assign(x = 'bar', pos = 1)
exists('bar')
#> [1] TRUE
rm(bar)

# Works because assign isn't in a pipe, and its special, default `pos` of
# `-1` refers to the function execution environment, as desired
exec(function() {
  assign('bar', 'foo')
  exists('bar', inherits = FALSE)
})
#> [1] TRUE
rm(bar)
#> Warning in rm(bar): object 'bar' not found

# Fails because the function's exec. env. is "overshot," and the assignment
# occurs in the global environment instead; no numeric position seems to work
exec(function() {
  'foo' %>% assign(x = 'bar', pos = 1)
  exists('bar', inherits = FALSE)
})
#> [1] FALSE
rm(bar)

# Works, presumably because the function's exec. env. happens to be exactly 6
# frames back from the environment in which the `assign()` call is evaluated, in
# this specific case
exec(function() {
  'foo' %>% assign(x = 'bar', pos = caller_env(6))
  print(exists('bar', inherits = FALSE))
  print(bar)
})
#> [1] TRUE
#> [1] "foo"

# Fails for unknown reasons - maybe there's a `caller_env()` value that would
# work, but I haven't found it
exec(function() {
  list <- list(bar = 'foo')
  list2env(list, envir = caller_env())
  exists('bar', inherits = FALSE)
})
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Even with your caveat I still question the need for this — just use the resulting named list inside the function, instead of using individual variables.

Comment: I hear you. In this case, FWIW, I'm preparing for a large and complex `dbplyr` query, involving 9 remote tables, possibly with self-joins, so I want to just be able to refer to `foo` instead of `tbl(con, 'foo')`, or even `remote_tbls$foo`, throughout. Though, I guess I could evaluate the whole query expression within a `remote_tbls` list, couldn't I? I.e., `with(remote_tbls, {query})`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most reliable *and* simplest way is to store the function’s environment in a name and refer to the name.

```
f = function () {
    env = environment()
    'foo' %>% assign('bar', envir = env)
    foo
}
```

And if you’re not using a pipe, `list2env` works directly:

```
g = function () {
    list = list(foo = 'bar')
    list2env(list, envir = environment())
    foo
}
```

But in both cases I would *generally* recommend sticking with a list and avoid assigning variables into the calling env; the following is equivalent to `g`:

```
g2 = function () {
    list = list(foo = 'bar')
    list$foo
}
```